# Craft CMS database caching in Queue?

Tags: database, yii, queue, craftcms

I’m having trouble figuring something out. I don’t yet have a lot of experience with Craft CMS or the Yii framework it’s build on but this is my current situation.

From an external API, I make a request to a custom endpoint that I have made in craft which adds a new job to the Queue. The job is responsible for making a request for each language (4 languages in my case so 4 requests). It looks something like this:

```
foreach ($map as $siteId => $language) {
  $response = $guzzleclient->get(.../language); // Get content in a certain language
  $entry = Entry::find($id)->...
  if ($entry) {
    Update existing entry...
    \Craft::$app->elements->saveElement($entry);
  } else {
    Create entry with $id...
    \Craft::$app->elements->saveElement($entry)
  }
}
```

But what this does is generate 4 seperate entities. Meaning everytime I try to do $entry = Entry::find() it returns null and makes a new entry.

Meanwhile when I put this exact code in a console command, it works perfectly. The first time it enters the foreach loop, it doesn't find an entry so it creates a new one, and the second time it enters the foreach, it does retrieve the previously made entry and it just updates the entry.

This seems like an issue where the entry is only saved in memory and it only flushes everything to the database at the end of the job meaning that when I do Entry::find it has no clue about the newly created entry. In doctrine there is something like entitymanager->flushAndClear() and I tried to look for something like that for Yii (found \Craft::$app->db->schema->refresh();) but that doesn't seem to help either...

Does anyone know a solution?